# how to create a domain for CustomUserStoreManager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have created a CustomUserStoreManager and deployed as per the doc https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/next/setup/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager/

- I am not able to see any errors nor the CustomeUserStoreManager in
  the DropDown as said in the doc.
- I need to map the CustomerStoreManager to a user store properties like a table, query, DB properties for each customeruserstore,  how to do that? where to do the config for the same.

I am using WSO2 IS 5.9

Comment: Check whether your component getting activated properly https://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-debug-wso2-carbon-products-using.html

Comment: Getting this error -- **** Required Bundle manifest headers do not exists: C:\WSO2IS~1.1\WSO2IS~1.0\bin\..\repository\components\dropins\CustomReadOnlyJDBCUserStoreManager-1.0.0.jar *****   
I had to remove <packaging>bundle</packaging> in pom.xml to compile and gen jar files else it wont happen for me !!! 
Also i tried wso2server.bat  -DosgiConsole and check for active components and didnt see this CustomeUserStoreManager !!!

Comment: You need to build the project as a bundle. Otherwise, WSO2 will not recognize it.